# Prevent mixed content error when embedding HTTP frame inside an HTTPS parent

Tags: javascript, html

When I embed an **HTTP** frame inside an **HTTPS** parent, I get a security error in Chrome & Firefox. Is there any workaround to use an *iframe* tag without getting this error?

Comment: Is the iframe also offered in https ? I mean, if so you can simply use `//` instead of `http://`

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox, there is a preference you can set (security.mixed_content.block_active_content) that will let you see the contents of the iframe. If this is an internal site, you may able to get all your users to switch this preference, but then you're disabling an important security setting. If this is a public site, this is not feasible.

You should [modify your site to avoid mixed content](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aA3l6nKvfzOUJ%3ahttps://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/MixedContent/fix_website_with_mixed_content+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ca).